# Images not loading correctly on Carousel Slider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

I do not know what is wrong with this image loading inside the slider , also I thought this has something to do with the debug but the release version has the same problem, overall all the pictures load slowly and have some delay but this problem is worse.

```
Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: Platform.isAndroid ? 85.0 : 115.0),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CarouselSlider(
                          aspectRatio: 1.1,
                          viewportFraction: 0.6,
                          initialPage: 0,
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          reverse: false,
                          autoPlay: false,
                          enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          onPageChanged: (index) {
                            if (!mounted) return;
                            setState(() {
                              _current = index;
                              SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
                                  [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
                            });
                          },
                          items: [
                            slides("words", "assets/images/Academic_Words.jpg", "Academic\n   Words", MyAppWords()),
                            slides("writing", "assets/images/writing.jpg", "Academic\n   Writing", MyAppWriting()),
                            slides("conference", "assets/images/conference.jpg", "Academic\nConference", EnterPhone()),
                            slides("conversation", "assets/images/conversations.jpg", "Academic\nConversations", null),
                            slides("correspondence", "assets/images/correspondence.jpg", "Academic\nCorrespondence", MyAppCorrespondence()),
                          ].map((imgUrl) {
                            return Builder(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 9.0),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(48.0),
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                            color:
                                                Color.fromRGBO(50, 50, 50, 1),
                                            blurRadius: 5.0,
                                            // has the effect of softening the shadow
                                            spreadRadius: 5.0,
                                            // has the effect of extending the shadow
                                            offset: Offset(
                                              -1.0,
                                              // horizontal, move right 10
                                              8.0, //
                                              // vertical, move down 10
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ]),
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48.0),
                                      child: imgUrl,
                                    ));
                              },
                            );
                          }).toList()),
                    ]),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(48.0)),
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(237, 237, 237, 1),
                ),
              ),
            ]);
          },
        ));

  }

   slides(String _tag,String _asset, String _title, Widget myF ){
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Hero(
            tag: _tag,
            child: Image.asset(
              _asset,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Colors.black45,
                  Colors.black54
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                  _title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontFamily: "Raleway"),
                ),
              )
        ],
      ),
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return myF;
              })),
    );
  }
```

here is a demonstration of my problem=> http://uupload.ir/view/k2ub_video_2019-10-22_10-14-47.mp4/

Comment: Could be the size of the image if it's much bigger than the others.

Comment: Code Poet:. The problem is when I scroll to the left or right, images keep coming and going like a pulse and maybe even load after a few seconds, is this also because of the size maybe?

Comment: I think it's likely to be the size, yes, in my experience

Comment: thank you @CodePoet that was the main issue

Answer (score 0):

The behavior seems to be caused by the scaling of the large image. Since `carousel_slider: 2.0.0`, it's recommended to pass `CarouselOptions` to options - wherein you can define either the height or aspect ratio for the carousel items.